# How to get a products variant id from order products details in bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to know which variant of a particular product is present in products in an order. I was not able to find variant ID of a variant in
the order product response from order product api provided by `bigcommerce`.

How can get the variant id from order products of a particular order using `bigcommerce` api ?

Answer (score 0):

The Orders API doesn't currently return the V3 variant ID, although it does return the variant SKU. This is something we plan to build out in the future, both for the server to server and storefront Orders APIs.